# sending text from form texteara to email

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have problem with sending a lot of text (like two pages )in word through the textarea which is going to be shown there. But, when I press the submit button it is sending only the first part  or number of characters maybe 100 to the email.

-First question

Is the textarea number of characters limited when sent?

this is the code i use

-Second question

Can I send the whole text to the email by just using html mailto?

`

```
<FORM id="usrform" ACTION="MAILTO:youremail@host.com?subject=REPORT" METHOD="POST" enctype="text/plin">
<span>Copy your Resume*</span><br>
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT">
</FORM>
<textarea form="usrform"  style=" width:500px;" name="Resume" cols="500" rows="100" maxlength="2000"></textarea><br>

</html>
```

`

Comment: why is your textarea outside of the form element?

Comment: @Bindrid I tried to keep it within the form and outside the form both works fine. The problem is with sending the text through mailto to the mail. I was wondering if mailto have specific character that could get from a form?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your textarea is not even between form tag and from your code you are not including it to form content.
2. `enctype="text/plain"` not `plin`.
3. Your textarea has `maxlength="2000"` that will restrict text length to 2000 characters (no matter visible or not).
4. Your server may limit how big post data may be.
5. You can send text using `mailto`. Need to include `body` parameter and encode your data. [More info here](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/mailto.htm).
6. Why are you mixing code styles? Why some tags lowercase, some uppercase?

Comment: 1. I tried to keep the textarea inside and outside both worked the same way. 2. I correct my mistake. Thank you. 3. Even if I did not include the “maxlength” it send limited characters.4. If this is the problem how can I fixed it.5.in the real code I include the body and I have better indentation.6.sorry for mixing code style I will try to focus next time.

Comment: @sara 1. - Keep all form elements within form. Always. 4. Change php.ini file settings; Is it possible for you to use PHP side mailing?

Comment: Thank you, I will learn PHP. However, do you think that the mailto have certain amount of characters to send?

Comment: @sara Quick look on internet shows that chrome may have 2000 chars limit. Some told it's windows problem. I personally only send via PHP and never faced such issue

Comment: thank you so much really you helped me a lot I am going to try learning PHP and create it.